# Out-Of-Bag estimate in scikit-learn

Tags: bootstrap, scikit-learn, bagging

I am using a bagging model from the Python [Scikit-Learn module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
ensemble = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(),
                             bootstrap=True,
                             bootstrap_features=False,
                             oob_score=True)
ensemble.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

By default the maximum number of samples and features drawn from X_train is set to 1.0. Does that mean that in that case there is no bootstrap occurring at all since all samples are being used? How is the oob_score calculated then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does that mean that in that case there is no bootstrap occurring at all since all samples are being used?

No. Bootstrap draws with replacement (as the help page you linked explains), so on average only $1 - \frac{1}{e} \approx \frac{2}{3}$ of the cases are drawn into the training set.

I guess it is time to read up about the bootstrap, bagging, and out-of-bag estimates, e.g. the references that help page gives.